# How to add one more query string with search query string

Tags: search

I am using WordPress to create a recruitment site with subscription. 
This is what I did. 
Added a meta value for user role 'rec' which is a date of ending of subscription.

All worked fine.

But when recruiter searches from the form it ads ?as=something as the query string.

I want my url structure to be like this

```
/recruitment/?uid=4&as=it
```

uid is the User ID of a recruiter, it is being used to get the meta of date from user's data to find out if user can see this page or not. ?as=something is search string.

Right now whatever I add in the action of form when a user searches the url becomes

```
/recruitment/?as=it
```

What I did was I added the code like this in search form.

```
<form method="get" id="sul-searchform" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>&uid=<?php echo $my_uid;?>" class="wg_search">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: LOL Sometimes I act dumb. 
'<?php $my_uid = get_current_user_id(); ?> '

Solved it through current user ID. There was no need of adding an extra query string.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer, then come back in two days and accept your own answer

Comment: I am new to the platform it said I need to wait for one day before I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ['add_query_arg'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) function, to do this.

It adds a single key & value or an associative array. You can set a key value to false to remove it from the query. Omitting the old query or the uri (second or third parameter) uses the $_SERVER value.

So in your case doing it like this should work:

```
... action="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'uid', get_current_user_id(), get_permalink() ); ?>" ...
```